What is solution of missing deployment name and replaced by model on Azure Ai Studio?
I've been using Azure AI Studio and Azure OpenAI Studio for a while now, and I'm currently working on implementing a RAG (Retrieval-Augmented Generation) technique using Prompt Flow. However, I've encountered an issue.
Previously, in Azure AI Studio's Prompt Flow, there was an option to connect to Azure OpenAI resources by selecting the "deployment name" of our deployed models. This was also documented in the official Microsoft guide on "How to build with Prompt Flow - Azure AI Studio" (step 8 clearly shows the "deployment name" option). However, this option now appears to have been replaced by "model," and as a result, I’m unable to connect to my deployed models or use the models listed on the portal.
Is this a bug in Azure AI Studio, or is the AI Studio undergoing some sort of revamp? I would appreciate any insights or solutions regarding this issue.
I have tried azure ai studio documentation, copilot support, chatGPT support, watched videos regarding this but still no solution.
